# Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents events don't work with WeakEventManager

Tags: wpf, weak-events, weakeventmanager

When I do

```
WeakEventManager<SystemEvents, EventArgs>
    .AddHandler(null, nameof(SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged), OnDisplaySettingsChanged);
```

My `OnDisplaySettingsChanged` never gets called. However, if I instead use normal event subscribtion via `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += OnDisplaySettingsChanged` everything works fine.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's `WeakEventManager`'s fault. When the event is fired, it implies that `source` will be `null` for static event sources (code excerpt from the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs,354)):

```
protected void DeliverEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ListenerList list;
    object sourceKey = (sender != null) ? sender : StaticSource;
    ...
```

But `sender` is never `null` for `SystemEvents`. Instead it passes a private instance of `SystemEvents`, `WeakEventManager` then assumes it's another instance it didn't previously know about and doesn't call the handler.

Here's the workaround I came up with:

```
class EventProxy
{
    private readonly Action<EventHandler> _subscribe;
    private readonly Action<EventHandler> _unsubscribe;

    public EventProxy(Action<EventHandler> subscribe, Action<EventHandler> unsubscribe)
    {
        _subscribe = subscribe;
        _unsubscribe = unsubscribe;
    }

    private EventHandler _event;
    public event EventHandler Event
    {
        add
        {
            if (_event == null)
                _subscribe(OnEvent);
            _event += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            // ReSharper disable once DelegateSubtraction
            _event -= value;
            if (_event == null)
                _unsubscribe(OnEvent);
        }
    }

    private void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _event?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var proxy = new EventProxy(h => SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += h, h => SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= h);
WeakEventManager<EventProxy, EventArgs>.AddHandler(proxy, nameof(EventProxy.Event), OnDisplaySettingsChanged);
```

Some explanation:

- `SystemEvents` holds a strong reference to `EventProxy`, which holds a weak reference to the handler (via `WeakEventManager`)
- When `WeakEventManager` subscribes to the event inside `AddHandler`, the proxy subscribes to the original event
- `EventProxy` acts as a proxy between the static event and the handler, invoking the handler whenever the original event fires
- After the handler gets collected, `WeakEventManager` will eventually run a cleanup, discover that the handler is dead and unsubscribe
- This will cause the proxy to unsubscribe from the original event, and, eventually, get collected by GC